# views pass argument for number of records to display to pager contextual filter?

Tags: views, paging

Drupal 7.

Is it possible to pass an argument to the contextual filter to limit number of items to display in a View from the UI?

IOW: can you pass an argument that replicates the Number Of Items portion of the Pager?

I have a node form which uses View Fields to display a view of related items. I want to pass an argument via the Field Display which limits the # of records.

If this must be done programmatically, how do I hook into the view 'contextually'... ie. so that the hook overrides the Number Of Items when the visitor is on a particular page (a Node of a certain Content Type.)

Comment: Do you mean programmatically or by way of the URL?

Comment: I mean via the URL. I edited the question, which I -thought- was straightforward. <sigh> I'm getting tired of re-creating the same view over and over depending on where it's called from. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible through the Views interface. But I think you could probably do it through a small custom module.

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_build(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'view_name') {
    $limit = $arg(1) //where $arg is the argument from your url
    $view->items_per_page = $limit;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Then I guess I need one more 'if'. How do I filter this so that it only applies the limit if the page being displayed is a) a node and b) is of a certain content type?

Comment: It depends on how you have your view set up. If you happen to be using a contextual filter for content type, that will be available in the view var you get passed in the pre_build. So if you happen to have ether the NID or Content Type as contextual filters, that would be in $view['args'][(position it's in in the view)].

Answer (score 1):

In depth you can do something like this:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_pre_build().
 */
function modulename_views_pre_build(&$view) {
  // Offset: starting point (position) of the subset of nodes
  if (!empty($_REQUEST['offset'])) {
    $offset = (int) $_REQUEST['offset'];
    if ($offset >= 0) {
      $view->set_offset($offset);
    }
  }
  // Limit: is the number of nodes to return
  if (!empty($_REQUEST['limit'])) {
    $limit = (int) $_REQUEST['limit'];
    if ($limit >= 0) {
      $view->set_items_per_page($limit);
    }
  }
}
```

Now when you'll execute your view the URL should be something like this:

http://an-awesome-drupal-site/your-view-path?limit=25&offset=5 and its done ;-)