# Pass argument to view for pager limit

Tags: views, 8

It is possible to pass and argument to a view for the limit on its pager? I see that there is [this question for Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130082/views-pass-argument-for-number-of-records-to-display-to-pager-contextual-filter), but not Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_build().
 */
function customModule_views_pre_build(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'your_view_id') {
   //- Set the new limit here // 3
   $view->setItemsPerPage(3);
  }
}
```